# VS Code .NET Core Intellisense not showing suggestions for namespaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-framework, intellisense

I'm using VS Code 1.40.0 on Mac. When I create a new .NET Core 3 console project and open a class file, I don't have IntelliSense showing me possible auto-imports.
For example in a new class file I want to declare a variable of type `List`, there's no suggestion given and the type is not recognized.

How can I fix this?
[Screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZzrM.gif)

Comment: Your recording (quite small btw) does not show the status bar. Do you have the “flame” icon next to the error/warning count? The tooltip should read “OmniSharp server is running”.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the suggestion to make a better recording! The "OmniSharp server" is running it says.